# Deploying an iOS Application Using Apple Enterprise Developer Program

Tags: ios

I have created an application for a company that I need to deploy. The application is for internal use only so it will not be available on the App Store. Do I need a UDID for each individual on whose device the app will be installed? That would be impossible since there are 500 employees. Does anyone have a good documentation or experience on deploying the iOS iPhone application using the Enterprise Developer Program only.

Comment: @azamsharpI am facing the same problem, can you please tell me the correct way that how can i publish my app in multiple employees using IOS Enterprise program? Thanks

Answer (score 24):

With the Apple **ENTERPRISE** Developer Program you can **NOT** distribute an App in the Apple AppStore.

Its purpose is to collaborate an In-House App in your own company.

The Enterprise account does not necessarily need the UDID of your target devices. You can for instance also use a link which remotely installs the app directly on the device.

You can find more details here: https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/

Comment: Hi, if I enroll in enterprise program, are the devices should be owned by the company or we can install the app to the employee's phone? I just read this article in the link below, it is said that the devices must be owned by the organizations. is that true? : https://www.knowband.com/blog/mobile-app/share-ios-app-without-publishing-on-apple-app-store/

Comment: really need your info, because I have no experience in enterprise app :(

Answer (score 22):

If you are trying to **deploy applications to customers/users on a production/long term basis**, you can deploy an applications outside the apple store in three ways:

1. manually via iTunes
2. directly via iTunes Configuration utility
3. via weblink (sent via mms, email, webbrowser etc.)

In order to distribute an application this way, the application must have a special corporate signature, and each device must have a matching corporate signature installed manually.

The best overall explanation for the process is available at this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html).

---

If you're just **testing on a handful of test devices**, then you I would suggest two approaches:
a dev release to a test device follow step by step instructions [here](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/04/24/tutorial-list-guideline-for-building-ad-hoc-application-for-iphone/).

---

Or you can use a **helper application to deploy a beta release**: [testflightapp](http://testflightapp.com).

Comment: Thanks for help but still I cant figure out, My Client has enterprise account and now I need to distribute app which we have developed, how can I move ahead. please share some document or something from which I can get easy idea for distribution

Answer (score 7):

You can do distribute your iOS app to only a particular set of people (in your case, your company employee), by following these procedure

1. Get a apple enterprise developer account
2. Create a distribution certificate and provisioning profile
   (In-House) using your enterprise developer account
3. Archive the ipa file using the created certificate and
   provisioning profile
4. While saving the ipa, click on the check mark. So, the plist file
   is also created.
5. Host the plist and ipa file in your server
6. Include a download html file with a href tag with src
   "itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://mydomain.com/apps/MyInHouseApp.plist"

Now when you click on the link from your device the app will get downloaded.

Comment: `While saving the ipa, click on the check mark`. But I can't find the check mark.

Comment: @Gank: Check this link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25910387/xcode-6-save-for-enterprise-deployment-does-not-create-plist-for-ipa-anymore"

Comment: Thanks! But I don't have a https SSL. The dropbox can't be visited in China, so I can't use that either. How to get a free https in my server's nginx?

Comment: The application would only be usable by the devices listed in the associated AdHoc provisioning profile. So TestFlight is a probably more use and easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with the previous answer. Check [this document](http://images.apple.com/iphone/business/docs/iOS_Deployment_Technical_Reference_EN_Feb14.pdf) page 26.

> MDM servers can deploy both App Store apps and in-house enterprise
>   apps to  devices over the air. Both paid and free App Store apps can
>   be managed by an  MDM server using Volume Purchase Program (VPP)
>   managed distribution.

Once you have VPP and Enterprise Developer account you could be able to install apps in the app store or company owned apps into the managed devices.

Further for just deploying the in-house app you could follow [this](http://readwrite.com/2010/12/15/apple-best-kept-secret-how-to-do-ad-hoc-installs#awesm=~oxNK4EbJR7RlVx) 9 step process.

Comment: Yes, MDM servers can install both public and private apps but you shouldn't publish an internal app to the App Store.

Comment: @Anand This [link](http://readwrite.com/2010/12/15/apple-best-kept-secret-how-to-do-ad-hoc-installs#awesm=~oxNK4EbJR7RlVx) is not available. I want to develop app for app store that should uses MDM server. Could you please guide me about prerequisites e.g purchasing which apple account, developing own MDM server etc.

Comment: @Anand I want to develop app for app store that should be used unlimited users. App should enroll itself on MDM server and setup configuration files. There is an App which is doing the same thing. I want to know how to do that, what are the prerequisites etc. Thank in Advance

Comment: Which answer is "the previous answer"? They're ordered by number of votes so it changes over time.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to deploy to many devices i suggest AirWatch. I've used it many times, it can be a bit frustrating to set up but once you have it working its very nice to have.

Answer (score -1):

Testflight still requires udid and the limit is 100 for 1 year before you can reset.  Enterprise deployment is best method for in house apps.

Comment: This is not true, TestFlight requires users to register their devices but if you have an enterprise certificate you don't need to worry about the UDIDs