# Use IOS Enterprise Distribution to avoid rejection of App store

Tags: ios, in-house-distribution, ios-enterprise

I have an app which is compiled with Ad-Hoc.

However I failed to pass Apple's review when trying to deploy it to App store.
I just heard of another deployment way: **Enterprise program(In-House app)**.

Want to know 2 points:

**1. Whether users could download the app and install it in iTunes totally for free?**

**2. Whether I could provide my app to all users who want it?**

Thanks.

Comment: Since you don't actually want (or probably qualify for) enterprise deployment, then no, that won't work for you at all. Why not fix the issues in your app and submit to the store again?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple policy.  If the question were about getting his app to pass app-store review, the question might be on-topic (maybe).

Comment: @nhgrif Actually, "how to pass" is the most important thing for me.

Comment: @rmaddy Maybe I am looking for a solution which is in extreme. However, The point is that I do want a solution.

Comment: As I said in my comment, if you would instead provide some details on why your app isn't passing and make your question be about how to change the code in order to store pass app store review, this question might be closer to on-topic.  But as long as it is about app store policy and not about code, it's off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

The iOS Developer Enterprise Program is intended for distributing In-house apps to other people working for the same company. Details are on Apple's page describing the [iOS Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/). You need to be a company or organization with a D-U-N-S number to apply to join this program. According to the agreement you are also only allowed to distribute to others in your organization. The cost per year is $299. So this is likely not a useful option for you.

Comment: Although there may be some exceptions (such as easier use of GNU-licensed libraries, *careful/reluctant* use of private APIs), in general you'd still want to adhere to the majority of AppStore submission requirements, except of course the once to allow the application to be accessible to all users.

Comment: @torrey.lyons thanks. Another thing I want to know: how could Apple know 'whether this man is one of those employees of my company'? If Apple could not know that, does it mean anyone who knows the link of my app  is able to install the app?

Comment: @JasperBlues Thanks for your comment. Actually my app has been rejected for App store deployment. It seems that the review rule is so strict that although I have adjusted my app for times, I am still not able to publish it. Want to find a way to avoid the rejection and introduce my app to users. :)

Comment: Why did Apple reject your App? Code quality issues can easily be fixed. Or censorship? Apple won't publish an App that they feel will offend certain users / doesn't meet their guide-lines. App still has merit? Change it to meet guidelines (best choice) Or look at the Cydia distribution channel, although this is a very narrow audience group - users who are comfortable with Jail-breaking.

Comment: Incidentally, Jailbreaking and Cydia are *not* illegal: The electronic frontier foundation successfully argued this in court a number of years ago. . Having said that the AppStore is a very healthy eco-system and security plays a big part in this.

Comment: @JasperBlues My app is rejected mainly because Apple thinks it seems to be a website which pretends to be native app. Thanks a lot, guy. Your point is quite professional!

Answer (score 0):

the easy answer is yes - but the more involved answer is that all users who download the app need to be employees of the company you are coding as.
the license agreement from apple is VERY strict on this.
in addition, the enterprise program is (If i remember right) about US$400/year.

Comment: Sounds like the easy answer is no, actually...

Comment: it's $299/year : [Apple's Site](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/)
good overall SO [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7829321/2115477)