# Can I upload a intranet app to App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store

I have a app which control other devices in intranet, and this app need login at first.
I want to know can I upload it to App Store?
How can I provide a account to apple employe to test my app?

Comment: if your app have some server you should provide links and manuals to reviewer, or give access to your network, you should understand that app must accessible for users too.

Comment: if account provided by you can be accessed through internet means you can provide the creaditials in addition info field

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deploying an iOS Application Using Apple Enterprise Developer Program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261255/deploying-an-ios-application-using-apple-enterprise-developer-program)

Comment: Check apple docs man. http://www.apple.com/iphone/business/it/deployment.html

Answer (score 1):

If this app can be used on "any" intranet and login can be done through Internet, then just provide username and password in Demo Account Information field in iTunes Connect.

If this app only works in your intranet and 99.99% of the App Store users will not be able to use it, then I cannot see why it should be on the App Store, and I think Apple will agree and not let it pass the approval process.

Comment: Apple ask me to upload a video first