# Enterprise Application : Android vs iOS applications

Tags: android, ios

For developing enterprise application in Android. I did the following things.

1. Create admin account.
2. Create publisher account for publish andriod app.

For android app, I can upload the app in Playstore. People having my office mail id can view and download the app.

Can anyone tell me about how this scenario works for ios enterprise application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261255/deploying-an-ios-application-using-apple-enterprise-developer-program

Comment: Thanks, So the ios enterprise scenario is completely differ from Android right.  Finally I figured out the point , is through ios enterprise application we can host our app in our domain not in itunes. And if we upload any new versions , we need to inform our employees to install the updated one.

Comment: Exactly right, you must inform about ur updates to ur employees becoz it is not available in app store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iOS entreprise application you should :

1- Have to be (at least an admin) team member of the iOS Developer Enterprise Program

2- Have a valid SSL certificate for the domain where you want to put the app.

This is a good article where you can find the steps that allows you to work with iOS entreprise application : [Provision iOS IPA App for In-House Enterprise Distribution](http://johannesluderschmidt.de/provision-ios-ipa-app-for-in-house-enterprise-distribution/2993/)

Answer (score 0):

For an iOS Enterprise app you need to enroll in the iOS development enterprise program. This program allows you to distribute you app to employees to the organization on which the program is registered

The enterprise program does not include access to iTunesConnect, so you will have to distribute the app yourself. You can do this with Over The Air installation. You will need to make sure that this is only accessible to employees only.

An enterprise app will not be reviewed by Apple.