# What is save for Enterprise Deployment in iOS (XCode 7)

Tags: ios, deployment, app-store, ipa

When I select archive to generate an ipa file, I am being presented with 4 options. I understand 3 of them. I am not clear about the 4th option ie. **Save for Enterprise Deployment**. However if I select this option to generate an ipa file, that particular ipa file is getting installed on a device which is not added in Apple Development Portal. Why is this so?

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261255/deploying-an-ios-application-using-apple-enterprise-developer-program)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple has an `Developer Enterprise Program` which allows app distribution outside the app store.
Your company must have an Enterprise Program License you are unaware of because without program enrollment Xcode won't allow you to export for enterprise distribution (see attached image).

Some links below:

- [Apple Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/)
- [Enterprise Developer Resources](https://developer.apple.com/enterprise/)
- [Distributing Enterprise Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
One more question, how is Mobile Device Management and enterprise program related?

Comment: Apple's iOS Enterprise Program includes a mobile device management (MDM) solution. You can check the `device management` section in `Enterprise Developer Resources` link in the answer for more details.